# Reset the .NET Core SDK version used by Azure Pipeline agent

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I added the `Use .NET Core` taks in one of my pipelines in Azure DevOps so I can make use of an specific version of the SDK for a particular pipeline.

Unfortunately, I set the path to install to `$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet` and this options cached the version in the agent which in turn makes all pipelines using the agent to work with that SDK version.

I would like to revert this and make the agent to use the default value again. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you use private agent?

Comment: I am using the Hosted Agent from the Azure pipeline agent pool. Is that a private agent?

Comment: No, it is not private. So, just remove task `Use .NET Core` if you want to use default version

Comment: You should use `global.json` to select a version, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection, not using a task.

Comment: @LexLi You still need to install the correct .NET Core SDK on the agent using the `Use .NET Core` task. Otherwise you can't build anything.

Comment: @jessehouwing most common SDK versions are already there on Microsoft hosted agents, so almost all things can build. Even if a rare version is needed, I will install that in a custom step, other than relying on a task that I have little control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to revert this and make the agent to use the default value again. How can I do that?

If you are using the Hosted Agent from the Azure pipeline agent pool, you just need to remove the `Use .NET Core` taks in pipelines, which you want to make the agent to use the default `.NET Core` SDK version.

As we know, [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops):

> If your pipelines are in Azure Pipelines, then you've got a convenient
>   option to run your jobs using a **Microsoft-hosted agent**. With
>   Microsoft-hosted agents, maintenance and upgrades are taken care of
>   for you. **Each time you run a pipeline, you get a fresh virtual
>   machine. The virtual machine is discarded after one use.**
>   Microsoft-hosted agents can run jobs directly on the VM or in a
>   container.

So, the `.NET Core` SDK version will be default when you execute the pipeline next time without specific version of the SDK by the task `Use .NET Core`.

If the agent not use the default value, you should make sure if you are using the hosted agent and the default value SDK version in your mind is different from the actual default value:

[Microsoft-hosted agent](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/blob/master/docs/pipelines/agents/hosted.md)

Then you could use the command line task to show the default version:

```
dotnet --version
```

Hope this helps.